# changes need in url manager in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a url  `www.xy.de/glossar/anzeigen-programming`

I want to use this url as `www.xy.de/anzeigen-programming`.

Last parameters are a variable. I want to show content after searching from database respect to last parameter.In `urlmanager` what have to do?

Comment: what is your controller/action (and module if applicable) and what is the name of the last parameter? Also, please add urlManager code from your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update your routes in config file.
Simply add something like this:

```
'glossar/<page:\w+>' => '/',
```

more info about routes could be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)